# Creating folders in nested folders doesnt work

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to create hundred folders with another hundred nested folders in each of them.

I have made this code but it doesnt work:

```
for i in {0..100}
 do 
  mkdir "folder{$i}"
  topfolder = "folder{$i}"
  cd $topfolder
  for a in {0..100}
   do
    mkdir "folder{$a}"
   done
done
```

Could you please give me an advice?

Comment: Line 9: "Unexpected end when looking for """. Line 12: "syntax error: unexpected end of file".

Comment: Remove the spaces in your variable assignments for a start.

Comment: Do you really want to call your folders `folder{0}`, `folder{1}`, etc. with the curly brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make directories recursively, you need to enter the directory and then create sub-directories.

Here's the change you need to make.

```
for i in {0..100}
 do 
  mkdir "folder{$i}"
  cd "folder{$i}"
  for a in {0..100}
   do
    mkdir "folder{$a}"
   done
   cd ..
done
```

Comment: This is completely what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

There are no spaces in variable assignments in bash. Furthermore, your script can be simplified by using `mkdir -p`, which creates parent directories at the same time as subdirectories if they don't already exist:

```
for i in {0..100}; do
  for a in {0..100}; do
    mkdir -p "folder${i}/folder${a}"
  done
done
```

Another problem was that your curly braces were incorrectly positioned around your parameters (I am assuming that you want directories named `folder0`, not `folder{0}`).

As suggested by [gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) in the comments (thanks), the loops can actually be removed entirely:

```
mkdir -p folder{0..100}/folder{0..100}
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying. It looks definitely clearly.

Comment: Or even `mkdir -p folder{0..100}/folder{0..100}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf very nice, I've added your suggestion to my answer, thanks.